# White screen after log in to Control Panel, after upgrade from v2.9.2 to 2.10.2

Tags: ee2, upgrade, php-errors

After an upgrade from 2.9.2 to 2.10.2 the site was working normally in the browser, and the system login page accepted credentials.  After that was a white screen.

[Turning on error logging](http://www.mediasurgery.co.uk/blog/white-screen-of-death) in admin.php produced the following error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'login_state' in 'field list'
>
> SELECT `member_id`, `admin_sess`, `last_activity`, `fingerprint`, `sess_start`, `login_state` FROM (`exp_sessions`) WHERE `session_id` = 'b0e0c13fd814f8ce72c88a242ac269705f9c5df5'
>
> Filename: libraries/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 731

The database table *exp_update_log* indicates successful update to v2.10.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I located this line (found at 721) in **/system/expressionengine/libraries/Session.php** and removed *login_state* from the query - so from this:

```
ee()->db->select('member_id, admin_sess, last_activity, fingerprint, sess_start, login_state');
```

to this:

```
ee()->db->select('member_id, admin_sess, last_activity, fingerprint, sess_start'); // login_state
```

The control panel loaded up fine and all seems functional now.

I'm hoping this is just a bug in this particular upgrade path...  Or should I run an SQL query to add this column to the *exp_sessions* database table?

Comment: Amazing! This was super helpful.  I'm not sure what version of EE a client was running as they deleted their system folder....but I assume they were around EE 2.9 and I ran into this error when using the EE 2.11 files, so it's still a thing.

Comment: An added note that I had to manually restore the 'login_state' column in the 'exp_sessions' table (using PHPMyAdmin) when upgrading EE from v2 to v3.  This was throwing an exception during the v3 upgrade process, but could be done after completion.  To get the correct values for the column, refer to another working EE installation v3 or upwards.

Comment: it is working for me. Thanks